# ¿Evento click dentro de una etiqueta que tiene otro evento click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy creando una etiqueta en forma de una barra que contiene iconos, esta etiqueta tiene un evento `click` asociado que al activarlo me muestra un detalle. Ahora, el problema surge cuando quiero darle un evento `click` al icono, los cuales están contenidos dentro de la etiqueta mencionada y no se activa su evento, mas se activa el evento de la etiqueta padre.

Quiero evitar mover el icono fuera de la etiqueta y quisiera saber si hay una forma de hacer que su evento se active obviando el evento de la etiqueta que lo contiene.

Esta es mi etiqueta con un evento `click` la cual muestra un detalle en otra parte de la página:

```
<div class="bar-agent" onclick="show_detail_agent();">
    <p class="agent-data"></p>
    <span id="delete_agent" class="icon-delete">
        <img src="img/trash.png" alt="">
    </span>     
</div>
```

Lo que intento hacer es acceder al evento `click` del span con `id="delete_agent"` para que elimine esta etiqueta. Pero al estar contenida dentro de la etiqueta con `class="bar-agent"` no me deja acceder al span.

```
function _delete_agent(){
    $(".content-agents .bar-agent-content .bar-agent").on("click","#delete_agent", function(){
        console.log("aqui!");
    });
}
```

Comment: Hola, podrías editar tu pregunta y añadirnos tu código? Veríamos como lo tienes montado y que se le puede hacer, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problema

Cuando se quiere usar el selector de [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) para muchas clases, se deben separar con comas. Por ejemplo, para seleccionar todos los elementos de la clase `content-agents` **Y** todos los de `bar-agent-content` **Y** los de `bar-agent`:

```js
$(".content-agents, .bar-agent-content, .bar-agent")
```

Sin embargo, al seleccionar de esta forma, se asocia el evento al `div` principal, algo que no nos permitirá prevenir la propagación del evento o "*efecto burbuja*" (que el evento vaya escalando a elementos padre).

```js
$(".content-agents, .bar-agent-content, .bar-agent").on( ... );
```

> Efecto burbuja
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### Solución

Podemos asignar el evento directamente al `<span>` que contiene la imagen de esta forma:

```js
$(".content-agents, .bar-agent-content, .bar-agent").find("#delete_agent").click(function(e){
    // ...
});
```

Y, una vez que está asociado de esta forma, **para prevenir el efecto burbuja, el evento tiene que devolver `false`**.

```js
$(".content-agents, .bar-agent-content, .bar-agent").find("#delete_agent").click(function(e){
    // ...

    return false;  // previene el efecto burbuja (propagación del evento).
});
```

---

#### Código

```js
function _delete_agent(){
    $(".content-agents, .bar-agent-content, .bar-agent").find("#delete_agent").click(function(e){
        console.log("click en la imagen");
        // Prevenir el efecto burbuja
        return false;
    });
}


// Asociar el evento
$( document ).ready(function() {
    _delete_agent();
});

// Para mostrar texto cuando se hace click en el div
function show_detail_agent() {
    console.log('click en el div principal!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar-agent" onclick="show_detail_agent();">
    &lt;div empieza acá
    <p class="agent-data">---agent---</p>
    <span id="delete_agent" class="icon-delete">
        <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-logo-med.png" alt="">
    </span>
    acá termina el /div&gt;
</div>
```

---

> **Nota para JavaScript**
>
> Devolver `false` funciona con las funciones de [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). Si se
>   quiere prevenir el efecto burbuja en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), se debe
>   utilizar:
>
> ```
> event.stopPropagation();
> ```